# Given y_pred with categories 0,1,2 how do I select only categories 1 and 2 to perform metrics on in Keras?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, backend, tensor

Given the confusion matrix:

```
>  0   1   2
>0 10  3   4
>1 2   5   1
>2 8   5   9
```

how would you write an accuracy metric with the Keras backend that would measure accuracy of the following subsection only?:

```
>  1   2
>1 5   1
>2 5   9
```